# TIN Interpolation (DEM exceeds extent)

Tags: qgis

I am doing a TIN interpolation in QGIS 3.16.11. I have a polygon layer that has a bounding box and I select that layer for the extent by choosing "Calculate from Layer". However, the DEM that is created exceeds the extent, i.e., it extends outside of the bounding box. See this screenshot (the black rectangle is the bounding box):[image: Calculate from Layer]

However, if I choose "Draw on Canvas" and draw the same box, the DEM that is created falls within the drawn extent. See this screenshot: [image: Draw on Canvas]

Is there a reason for this behavior, i.e., why does the DEM exceed the extent of the bounding box when "Calculate from Layer" is chosen?

Comment: Try Layer Properties - Source - Update extents

Comment: I went to Layer Properties and clicked Update Extents under Source, but it didn't solve the issue. The extent still exceeded the bounding box. Under Layer Properties/Information, I now see that the extents are shown larger than they are supposed to be and the feature count is one. I just now created a new polygon layer and copied and pasted the old bounding box feature into it. Now it works as expected. I guess there must have been some artifact in the shapefile, but it didn't show up in the attribute table. I guess it will remain a mystery, but the issue seems to be solved for now.